# Enable/disable button if value is different than select by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to toggle a button state between enabled/disabled if I change the default value of a select element. Take this HTML as example:

```
<select 
    ng-change="statusBtn(btnUpdFee, updFee)" 
    ng-options="wt.id as wt.name for wt in wtax" 
    ng-model="updFee" 
    class="ng-pristine ng-valid"
>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">cm-534be5d66aea3</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">cm-534be5d681a02</option>
    <option value="2">cm-534be5d68316e</option>
</select>

<button disabled="" ng-click="showCommentModal('updateFee')" class="btn btn-success" id="btnUpdFee"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
```

And this is the code I wrote but it's not working:

```
$scope.statusBtn = function(btnId, curValue) {
    if (curValue != $scope.updFee) {
        $("#" + btnId).removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#" + btnId).attr("disabled");
    }
}
```

What I miss?

**EDIT**

I made some changes and now code look like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="showCommentModal('updateFee')" ng-disabled="!btnStatus"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>

$scope.$watch("updFee", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue === oldValue) {
        $scope.btnStatus = false;
    } else {
        $scope.btnStatus = true;
    }

    console.log($scope.btnStatus, newValue, oldValue);
});
```

And this is the output:

```
First Page Load (no changes): false undefined undefined
First Page Load (no changes): true 2 undefined
Changing SELECT: true 1 2
Changing SELECT again: true 3 1
```

But still not working, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use jQuery to set properties like this in an Angular driven application! Use `ng-disabled` set to a flag. On `change` of your `select` - check what you need to and set the flag:

```
<button ng-disabled="isNotDefault" ng-click="showCommentModal('updateFee')" class="btn btn-success" id="btnUpdFee"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>

$scope.statusBtn = function(btnId, curValue) {
    $scope.isNotDefault = curValue != $scope.updFee
}
```

Comment: Still not working since button never goes back to the default state which is disabled

Comment: @ReynierPM -- You have to set the default value...the button will never be disabled since `curValue` will always equal `updFee`

Comment: Hmmm the default value is the current selected value of the select how I setup that? I need to use the same function in four different select so I'm trying to get this generic instead of personalized

Comment: Hard code the default value - `if updFee == "Default"`

Comment: Can't since values are dinamically

Comment: Is the default value located within the dynamic values at the same index?

Comment: Isn't always at the same index, it depends on user selection